# Why do people waste their time attacking the Smashville balloons and Duck Hunt birds?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I always see people in tournament matches attacking the balloons and birds, and I wonder why... in high-pressure situtuations, doesn't it just waste time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of people don't because of what you mentioned, it wastes time and can possibly be punished. However, it adds new moves and pushes out old ones from the [nine-move staling list,](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Stale-move_negation) which can be useful for unstaling a smash attack for killing.